# ASP.Net Identity - cannot login with password

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-identity, asp.net-membership, membership

Having some issue with ASP.Net Identity. I am creating a user via:

```
 var manager = new UserManager<IdentityUser>(userStore);

                manager.UserValidator = new UserValidator<IdentityUser>(manager)
                {
                    AllowOnlyAlphanumericUserNames = false
                };

                manager.PasswordValidator = new PasswordValidator
                {
                    RequiredLength = 6,
                    RequireDigit = true,
                    RequireLowercase = true,
                    RequireUppercase = true,
                };

                 var user = new IdentityUser() { UserName = email.Text, Email = email.Text };                    
                 IdentityResult result = manager.Create(user, Password1.Text);
```

This then adds the user to the database. When I then try and login with this user it always returns "Password incorrect" even when the password was the same password used to create the account.

I am logging in using:

```
var userStore = new UserStore<IdentityUser>();
var userManager = new UserManager<IdentityUser>(userStore);


        userManager.UserValidator = new UserValidator<IdentityUser>(userManager)
        {
            AllowOnlyAlphanumericUserNames = false
        };

        var user = userManager.Find(email.Text, Password.Text);

        if (user != null)
```

Using SQL Profiler I can see that that it looks up the user correctly and when I run the SQL in SSMS I can see the row is returned fine.

I'm not sure why userManager.Find is returning null when the actual record count returned from the database is 1?

Comment: Is this an MVC application? I believe you should be using the SignInManager class.

Comment: If the profiler shows a query that returns data, it is no problem of the hashing algorithm. Add your manager `Create` and `Find` methods so it can reproduced

Comment: @Juan its an ASP.Net Web Forms project.

Comment: @bradbury9 I've added the full code. Both user managers are the same except the login doesn't have the password validator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `SignInManager`

```
SignInManager<IdentityUser> _signInManager; // Inject 

var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(email.Text, Password.Text, true, lockoutOnFailure: true);
```